# PHP base64_decode is returning hex or NULL

Tags: php, base64

I have a base64 string:

```
AgAAOwEwMzEyMTMwMDAwMDAwOTA0QG5haS5lcGMubW5jMTMwLm1jYzMxMi4zZ3BwbmV0d29yay5vcmc=
```

I can take the raw base64, copy and paste it and run it through bash's base64 -d or `php_decode()` and it works. But when I grab the variable from a post using file_get_contents('php://input') in PHP it wont work. However, I can log the JSON encoded post using `error_log()` and copy and paste form there and it works. I can echo the base64 value and everything appears normal. But as soon as I wrap base64_decode around the string, I get errors. If it matters, the first two characters of the decoded string is ";0". I thought possibly that may be causing PHP to assume its hex?

Sorry for the messy debug code, but this should illustrate some examples.

```
$sub_id = get_field($json[$i], "subscriber-id", "null");
error_log("type: " . gettype($sub_id));
error_log("$i raw:  |$sub_id|");
$decoded = base64_decode($sub_id);
error_log("$i decoded:  $decoded");
error_log("$i raw sub-id: " . $sub_id);
$iccid_a = array();
$raw_sub_id = $sub_id;
$ret = exec("echo \"$raw_sub_id\" | base64 -d ",$iccid_a);
error_log(print_r($iccid_a,1));
```

I get this output:

type: string

0 raw:  `|AgAAOwEwMzEyMTMwMDAwMDAwOTA0QG5haS5lcGMubW5jMTMwLm1jYzMxMi4zZ3BwbmV0d29yay5vcmc=|`

0 decoded:  \x02

0 raw sub-id:  `AgAAOwEwMzEyMTMwMDAwMDAwOTA0QG5haS5lcGMubW5jMTMwLm1jYzMxMi4zZ3BwbmV0d29yay5vcmc=`

Array\n(\n    [0] => \x02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decoded data begins with some non-printable characters that may not be playing well with whatever you're using as a display.

```
$ php -r 'echo base64_decode("AgAAOwEwMzEyMTMwMDAwMDAwOTA0QG5haS5lcGMubW5jMTMwLm1jYzMxMi4zZ3BwbmV0d29yay5vcmc=");' | hexdump -C
00000000  02 00 00 3b 01 30 33 31  32 31 33 30 30 30 30 30  |...;.03121300000|
00000010  30 30 39 30 34 40 6e 61  69 2e 65 70 63 2e 6d 6e  |00904@nai.epc.mn|
00000020  63 31 33 30 2e 6d 63 63  33 31 32 2e 33 67 70 70  |c130.mcc312.3gpp|
00000030  6e 65 74 77 6f 72 6b 2e  6f 72 67                 |network.org|
0000003b
```

I don't know what exactly you're expecting the decoded data to look like, but the problem is not with `base64_decode()`.